# How to convert dimensions of numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

```
Y_train.shape
```

Output is

```
(650,)
```

but I want output as

```
(650,1)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick-

```
Y_train = Y_train[:, np.newaxis]
```